# Is there a limit of nested arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I am experimenting on arrays in Ruby. I cannot access the maximum nested array count. Example
experiment is shown below:

```
array = [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

So, do you know a limit of dimensions of array in Ruby?

Comment: Is there a reason you would ever need more than 3 to 4 ?

Comment: I said this is only experiment

Comment: you could easily write a program that adds another layer of nesting until you encounter an error.

Comment: thanks for the answers. i think, best answer is out of memory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limit is when you run out of memory.

Comment: I think so, but many languages have limit some structures, for example if-else blocks.

Comment: @sbagdat: But that sort of thing wouldn't apply. A nested array is just an array that happens to contain an array that happens to contain an array ... The top level has no idea what's going on underneath.

Comment: The limit is when you get a stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Per commenter @HunterMcMillen's idea, you could test it like so:

```
# Warning: be prepared for a sad computer!
depth=0; arr=[]; a=arr
begin
  while true do
    b = []
    a.push(b)
    a = b
    depth += 1
  end
rescue => e
  puts "OK: depth=#{depth}, error=#{e} (#{e.class})"
end
```

Presumably at some point it will raise some error (e.g. out of memory) and you'll see how many arrays you were able to nest.